# How do I change the Embeds Description from a different command in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I have been coding my own Discord bot for a while now and I want to make a command that changes an embed from another command. I have a command handler.

When I do `-autostatus` my Discord bot will post an embed with latency, API latency, uptime, and status information on whether the bot is functioning fine.

I have got the "functioning fine" and uptime inside the .setDescription so then I can edit it from another command.  But when I do `-botoff`, I get the following error:

```
embed.setDescription("Uptime: Offline Bot Status: Offline")

TypeError: Cannot read property of 'setDescription' of undefined
```

Here is my `-botoff` command:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { embed } = require("./autostatus.js")
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
   if(message.author.id != "276249983664128001") return;
   embed.setDescription("Uptime: Offline Bot Status: Offline")
}
```

My *autostatus.js* can be found here: https://hastebin.com/pezinewiqi.js

Thanks so much if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `const { embed } = require("./autostatus.js")`
is undefined. This is because you are not exporting embed in autostatus.js.
I checked your hastebin and found

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("My Status!")
        .setDescription(`**Uptime:** \n \`${uptime}\` \n **Bot Status:** \`✅ Operational\``)
        .addField("Latency:", `\`${ping}\``)
        .addField("API Latency:", `\`${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}\``)
        .setColor(client.config.color)
        .setFooter(`${client.config.footer} | Last updated`)
        .setTimestamp()
```

Here by using `let` you are just creating a local variable. This can't be required from other files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the embed message ID in a global variable of your bot and then, in your other command, fetch the message by its ID and edit the content of the fetched message.